# Is Between dates into createCriteria method on Grails inclusive?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to find on grails documentation this information, but I couldn't find it so far.

I want to know if between into createCriteria on Grails is inclusive or not.

I have the following:

```
MyObject.createCriteria().list(params) {
   between 'date',dateFrom, dateTo
}
```

And I need to know if createCriteria on Grails is inclusive and if not how to make it inclusive.

Someone know where is this information?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#between(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), it issues a *between* constraint. The Grails [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) is not any clearer. However, according to [ANSI SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) it is inclusive.

> "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z".

So it seems that GORM/Hibernate leaves it up to the database. And if the database is ANSI SQL compliant then *between* is inclusive.